# Angular 9: Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I just developed sign in authentication for an Angular app and I went to test it. Sign up works just fine. Then I sign out and attempt to sign in and the header does not update as expected, instead I get this error in console:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
> "chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd" from accessing a
> cross-origin frame.
> at e [as constructor] (chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/lpfulllib.js:1:1441712)
> at new e (chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/lpfulllib.js:1:1444920)
> at chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/lpfulllib.js:1:1461728

But I am not authenticated because I get:

```
{authenticated: false, username: null}
authenticated: false
username: null
```

Even though the GET request itself went through successfully, but there is a problem there, because it's not supposed to be a GET but a POST request. Why does it think it's a GET request?

My `signin()` method inside my auth service clearly shows it's a post request:

```
signin(credentials: SigninCredentials) {
    return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + "/auth/signin", credentials).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.signedin$.next(true);
      })
    );
  }
```

Here is my auth http interceptor code:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpEventType,
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AuthHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Modify or log the outgoing request
    const modifiedReq = req.clone({
      withCredentials: true,
    });

    return next.handle(modifiedReq);
  }
}
```

Now I do not think the issue is in my `AuthHttpInterceptor`, I believe the problem is in `AuthService`:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";

interface UsernameAvailableResponse {
  available: boolean;
}

interface SignupCredentials {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  passwordConfirmation: string;
}

interface SignupResponse {
  username: string;
}

interface SignedinResponse {
  authenticated: boolean;
  username: string;
}

interface SigninCredentials {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class AuthService {
  rootUrl = "https://api.my-email.com";
  signedin$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  usernameAvailable(username: string) {
    return this.http.post<UsernameAvailableResponse>(
      this.rootUrl + "/auth/username",
      {
        username,
      }
    );
  }

  signup(credentials: SignupCredentials) {
    return this.http
      .post<SignupResponse>(this.rootUrl + "/auth/signup", credentials)
      .pipe(
        tap(() => {
          this.signedin$.next(true);
        })
      );
  }

  checkAuth() {
    return this.http
      .get<SignedinResponse>(this.rootUrl + "/auth/signedin")
      .pipe(
        tap(({ authenticated }) => {
          this.signedin$.next(authenticated);
        })
      );
  }

  signout() {
    return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + "/auth/signout", {}).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.signedin$.next(false);
      })
    );
  }

  signin(credentials: SigninCredentials) {
    return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + "/auth/signin", credentials).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.signedin$.next(true);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it could be a CORS error. Regarding your GET request, my best guess would be that the browser is sending a request to check the CORS policy. If you had access to the backend, I'd double check your CORS or a rate-limit.

Comment: Share your HttpInterceptor code.

Comment: @onrails, I just shared my AuthHttpInterceptor code.

Comment: Where are your headers?

Answer (score 0):

I see you have no HttpHeaders. While I do not see your backend configuration, I suspect the mis configuration causes your exception.

You can update your Angular interpector to something like this:

```
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Injectable()
export class AuthHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   // const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
   // const userToken = localStorage.getItem('id_token')

    if (token) {
      const authRequest = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         // Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
         // userID: `${userToken}`,
        },
      })
      return next.handle(authRequest)
    } else {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      })
      const cloned = req.clone({
        headers,
      })
      return next.handle(cloned)
    }
  }
}
```

Also make sure that your backend is aligned and headers such as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` configured to true

Comment: this solution did not work for me. Unfortunately I have no control over the backend.

Answer (score -1):

That is caused by LastPass extension. Deactivate it and the error will disappear.

Comment: This answer is not helpful. Specifying browser extensions that *may* cause errors is not a concrete solution.